# Развернуть окно удаленного рабочего стола на весь экран

Tags: windows, desktop

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Я открываю удаленный рабочий стол. Раньше у меня с ним всё было хорошо: это окно у меня открывалось на весь экран. В том числе у меня отображалась нижняя панель задач удаленного рабочего стола. Сейчас у меня удаленный рабочий стол открывается во весь экран, однако панель удаленного рабочего стола у меня не отображается. Вместо этого у меня отображается панель задач с моего основного рабочего стола. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Способ "Показать параметры - Экран - Настройка отображения - Сдвинуть ползунок в крайнее правое положение" не работает.

Answer (score 0):

После перезагрузки устройства и удалённого рабочего стола данная проблема решилась.